# ArcMap replication tool does not synchronize changes made in versioned view from SQL Developer!

Tags: arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, replication

I am trying to replicate a feature class from Oracle to MSSQL Server using one-way replication(parent-child) replication. The replication works when edits are made from ArcMap,since I have to insert bulk data in that version and finally replicate it therefore making edits/inserts from ArcMap is not feasible. 
Replication works on the default version and data in default version comes from a view that is created while registering the feature class as versioned. Therefore, I am inserting or editing data in that view. The data is also found in version's respective table i.e Add and Delete tables. But when I run synchronization, it does not migrate those changes to MSSQL Server made from SQL Developer.

Comment: Did you execute database compress before starting synchronisation? This will write back the changes from the Add and Delete tables to the business tables.

Comment: I don't want the data in base tables but in the target replica and for that it is not necessary to be compressed to base tables.